# How does the testing method and possibility of cheating in an entirely online degree affect the value of the degree?

Tags: united-states, cheating, reputation, online-degree

Although my question can't be answered absolutely, I'll try to state it in a way that's as close as possible.

I'm considering earning an entirely online Software Engineering bachelors degree from a school which also has an on-campus equivalent. But, most importantly: my exams will be all closed book.

It's very easy to cheat with closed book tests, I expect; even if they try to prevent it, just use a second PC or a virtual machine.

Because of how easy it is to cheat with this method of testing, is it a strong indicator that potential employers will place little value on my degree?

Comment: Adding a country tag would be helpful.

Comment: What's an **"_SE bachelors degree_"**?  In general, it's best to avoid acronyms like **"_SE_"** unless you're in a context in which constantly spelling something out would become tedious.  Here, "_SE_" is often used to refer to "_Stack Exchange_", though there isn't another term that's sufficiently common to merit an acronym.

Comment: Certainly some online courses issue a certificate identical to the on-campus ones; there's no way for anyone to tell it was "online". Taking a step back, there have been "distance learning" degrees for a long time e.g. Open University in the UK; if anything these are more prestigious than some ex-poly degrees.

Comment: Edited OP to say "Software Engineering." Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Being online and thus open to cheating on tests certainly reduces the value of the degree, as you suggest in your question.